# Moq Entity Framework Auditing on SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework-4, moq

Finding really hard to unittest with EF4.Must be lack of knowledge on my part.

I am doing some auditing using EF and I would like to test that a particular method on my AuditClass has been called when calling CustomerSave.

How would you approach this?
Can it be done?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really i have no unit testing knowledge but i can guide you to this [video](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx) from julie lerman where you can get some ideas creating a fake context for testing purposes. This requires extra work but its a solution for your problem.

Hope i helped, dont forget mark as answer :)